# How to pass a dataframe to the method of an object?

Tags: python, class, dataframe

Why does this code give the following error?

> TypeError: simple_returns() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
import datetime as dt
import math
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)

df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)


class CalcReturns:
    def simple_returns(self):
        simple_ret = self.pct_change()
        return simple_ret

    def log_returns(self):
        simple_ret = self.pct_change()
        log_ret = np.log(1 + simple_ret)
        return log_ret


myRet = CalcReturns()
c = df['Adj Close']
sim_ret = myRet.simple_returns(c)
print(sim_ret)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a parameter to the class's methods to receive the `pandas.Series` and be sure to apply the `pct_change()` method on the Series and not the class object with *self*:

```
class CalcReturns:
    def simple_returns(self, ser):
        simple_ret = ser.pct_change()
        return simple_ret

    def log_returns(self, ser):
        simple_ret = ser.pct_change()
        log_ret = np.log(1 + simple_ret)
        return log_ret


myRet = CalcReturns()
c = df['Adj Close']
sim_ret = myRet.simple_returns(c)
print(sim_ret)

# Date
# 2010-06-29         NaN
# 2010-06-30   -0.002511
# 2010-07-01   -0.078473
# 2010-07-02   -0.125683
# 2010-07-06   -0.160937
# 2010-07-07   -0.019243
# 2010-07-08    0.105063
# 2010-07-09   -0.003436
# 2010-07-12   -0.020115
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
sim_ret = myRet.simple_returns(c)
```

calls `CalcReturns.simple_returns()` and appears to pass only one parameter.  But methods on python classes are special, in that python also passes the object itself.  It does this in the first parameter.  This is the reason you see the pattern:

```
class MyClass():

    def my_method(self):
        """ a method with no parameters, but is passed the object itself """
```

The `self` is named self as a convention to remind us that it is the object.  So if you want to pass your dataframe you will need to change the method signature to look like:

```
def simple_returns(self, a_df):
```